# PHP: move_upload_file() saves file with wrong extension

Tags: php

Server:

> CentOS release 5.3 (Final) x86_64
>
> PHP 5.3.2
>
> Apache 2.2.3

PHP Code:

```
error_log('Move from: ' . $_FILES[$upload_name]["tmp_name"]);
error_log('Move to: ' . $save_path.$file_name);
if (!@move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$upload_name]["tmp_name"], $save_path.$file_name)) {
    HandleError("File could not be saved.");
    exit(0);
}
```

PHP error_log:

> [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] Move
>   from: /tmp/phpX9pxKt
>
> [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] Move
>   to:
>   /path/to/files/temp/**1301512183822bb.avi**

Actual file saved on file system:

```
1301512183822bb.XXX
```

Where XXX is three random letters/numbers, I have seen .cb2, .ozz, .abc, .oar, .jhz, list is never ending...

Summary: move_uploaded_files saves the file with a random extension.  Files contents are fine, the only problem is the file extension.

No updates were applied.  Nothing on the server changed.  This randomly started occuring.  Server has been running for months fine until now.  I've tried restarting apache, even tried a server reboot.

Comment: I'd bet on some code between error log and actual move.

Comment: Can you show how `$file_name` is generated?

Comment: I've tried hard coding my own file name into the move_uploaded_file() function, same results.

Comment: Remove *every single* `@` operator in the script -- you're *intentionally* discarding errors with it.

Comment: Still nothing.  Updated apache & php to newest versions.  The code snippt above is from the software ClipBucket if anyone is wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, it's bad code after what I pasted above.  The code for this software is poorly written.  I would suggest staying far from this software, even if it is free.

Comment: Clipbucket, not PHP.  See other comments.